# HTML: Header + Footer + Fluid Content with certain specifications

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I need to create a webpage, with a normal header + sticky footer + fluid body content stretched vertically.
However, these positions can't be absolute, as I need a page min-height of 780px.

I managed to acomplish this using tables, but I really want to avoid using them. Also I'd like to avoid the usage of JS or jQuery.
The sticky footer is only sticky until min-height is reached.

Sorry for all these specific terms, it's just that I'm struggling with this for quite some time. I've tried the usual sticky footer layout with the pusher , but my main content isn't stretched when I use height: 100% (it seems there's a bug when the wrapper uses height: auto).

Example image of what should happen: http://s22.postimg.org/6fvdd4mxd/layout.png

JS Fiddle to show what I have right now:
http://jsfiddle.net/6qatg/

The code:

```
<body>
    <table class="wrapper">
        <tr><td id="topBar" class="topBar">

        </td></tr>

        <tr><td valign="top" id="mainContent" class="mainContent">  
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td class="footer" id="footer">
        </td></tr>

    </table>
</body>

html{
    min-width: 790px;
    min-height: 300px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    /*border: 2px solid black;*/
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 790px;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer {
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #00F8FD;
    width: 100%;
}

.topBar{
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00F8FD;
}

.mainContent{
    background-color: #EEF8FD;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming I understand what you're asking correctly have you tried to make a div for the header and footer and set the position of each of those to position: fixed? That will hold them in place and you can have your main content scroll freely within that.

Comment: not clear - what s wrong with what you have so far?

Comment: @Alex: He said he doesn't want to use tables.

Comment: LOL ok ops I m blind thanks!

Comment: ok I ve done this http://jsfiddle.net/6qatg/2/ which can be useful - I understand @JordanPlahn what you suggest and I agree....not sure is what PO wants

Comment: @Jordan Yes I've tried that, but I don't want the footer to stick to the bottom when the min-height is reached. I've tried replacing the table elements with divs, and the only thing that's missing is something like "calc(100% - 75px - 35px)", but that isn't cross-browser friendly, as I want this to run on IE8.

Comment: @Alex Almost. I got this fiddle mixing all the answers I've been getting (thank you everyone!). http://jsfiddle.net/sv6LJ/

Made a crutial editing, because it seems I didn't explain myself too well. The header is not sticky, and the sticky footer should lose its "stickyness" once min-height is reached.

Got rid of the table, but I still get scrolling even with min-height:300px.

Comment: basically you want avoiding scrolling of the main content ?

Comment: I hope it's a bit more clarified now. I added this image to the original question: http://s22.postimg.org/6fvdd4mxd/layout.png

That's what should be happening. The middle is liquid until the page min-height is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried adding the heading and footer inside the content container? I've made the min height 500 for fiddle demo purposes, there is no scroll bars and the footer stays down at min height of 500 - or when set to 760 it will stay to that.

see this 
http://jsfiddle.net/carbontype/FYe2b/

**HTML**

```
<div class="contain">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="data">hello 123</div>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.contain{width:100%; height:100%;}
.header{height:50px; position:absoulte; top:0px; width:100%; background:red; z-index:10;}
.content{height:100%; position:relative; background:green; min-height:500px;}
.content .data{padding:10px;}
.content .footer{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px; width:100%; background:pink;}
```

Comment: @vitorOliveira this should be what you need.

Comment: I've put everything inside the content DIV and it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: EDIT: I just noticed that this solution doesn't work if I wanna use elements inside "data" that have fluid heights (65%, etc.) . Is there a workaround for that case? What I managed to get is a div that surpasses the footer by the header's height. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FYe2b/3/

I guess I can just take the header's height out of the min-height.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have understood what you're asking for? if not my apologys

```
<div class="contain">
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="data">hello 123</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
.contain{width:100%; height:100%;}
.header{height:50px; position:fixed; width:100%; background:red; z-index:10;}
.content{height:100%; position:relative; background:green; min-height:790px;}
.content .data{padding:80px 10px 10px 10px;}
.content .footer{position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px; width:100%; background:pink;}
```

Comment: I'm the one who sould apologize for being unclear. The header isn't really sticky, and the footer is only sticky until min-height has been reached. 

Here's the new fiddle without tables: http://jsfiddle.net/sv6LJ/

It still get a scroll even if I have a window height above min-height of 300px.

Comment: ok, the above should still work minus the fixed position - http://jsfiddle.net/carbontype/FYe2b/ take that and put it into a HTML file

Comment: That's almost it. The only problem now is that the min-height should be related to the html page, and the content always has overflow (it doesn't matter how much I stretch it, it always has a scrollbar).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by setting `position:fixed` to the header and footer (`.topBar,.footer`), and giving the main content area (`.maincontent`) a `min-height:780px;` along with some padding to compensate for the fixed header and footer.
**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/EN3Pj/1/ 
**HTML:**

```
<div id="topBar" class="topBar"></div>
<div id="mainContent" class="mainContent">
   Your content here...
</div>
<div class="footer" id="footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
html{
    min-width: 790px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif
}

body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    /*border: 2px solid black;*/
}
*{
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer {
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #00F8FD;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.topBar, .footer{
    position:fixed; //make header and footer fixed position
}
.topBar{
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color: #00F8FD;
}

.mainContent{
    background-color: #EEF8FD;
    min-height:780px; //set min-height for content
    padding-top:75px; //compensate for footer and header height
    padding-bottom:35px;
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I want. I've tried taking out the sticky footer when min-height is reached (sorry for being unclear in my previous post, I've edited it a bit), but it seems to me that the scrollbar shows up before I minimize my window to below 790px?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? This is just a rough outline, but I think it gives you what you went.

http://jsfiddle.net/T5xn3/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #00F8FD;
}

#body {
    height:600px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00F8FD;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The question has been edited and I've made some replies clarifying it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

if the wrapper  height auto don't work leave it at 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/6qatg/2/

```
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div    id="topBar" class="topBar">

        </div>

    <div id="mainContent" class="mainContent">  
        </div>

        <div class="footer" id="footer">
        </div>
```

css

```
  html{
min-width: 790px;
min-height: 300px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
height: 100%;
  }

 body{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
/*border: 2px solid black;*/
height: 100%;
min-height: 300px;
min-width: 790px;
}
 *{
margin: 0;
}

 .wrapper {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
   .footer {
height: 35px;
   background-color: #00F8FD;
width: 100%;
  }

.topBar{
height: 75px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #00F8FD;
}

 .mainContent{
background-color: red;
height: 100%;
```

}

Comment: This is almost it, the only problem is that it still has a scrollbar even if the window height is superior to the min-height in the CSS.