# HTML Resolution issues

Tags: html, css

I gave up!!!! I tried my best to fix the problem but I have no clue. My problem is dealing with the resolution, the width, and the different computers. I manage to organize the page the way I wanted on my computer but every time I go check it on another computer I get frustrated. I don't know if someone could take a look at my CSS code and HTML code and give me some feedback; I would, really, appreciate it. My images move and overlap with the text and other images when I try resizing the page. The footer moves up if I opened the page on a larger screen. I don’t want the scroll bar to appear unless if it’s needed. Normally a good page everything will stay where it supposed to be and if you resize the page the scroll bar appears and allows you to see what you are interested in. I placed 4 images on the bottom of the page (web) and 3 on top. 
I would appreciate it if someone could help with these issues. Thank you

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="mastercontainer">
         <div id="header"><font color="##FFFFFF" size="5">
            <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130543/html-header-footer-fluid-content-with-certain-specifications">
               <font color="#33FF00">
               <b> STACK </b>
               </font>
            </a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            The link "WEB-LINK"  on this footer moves from it's spot when the page is opened in a different screen </font>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp">
               <font color="#33FF00" size="5"> <b> WEB-LINK  </b> </font></a>
         </div>
         <div id="content">
            <div id="innercontentmiddle">
               <div style="position:absolute;left: 35%; top: 3%; z-index:1;">
                  <img src="NC.jpg" width="650" height="250" 
                       /title=" this picture moves as I resize the window">
                       <br>
               </div>
               <div style="position:absolute;left: 5%; top: 3%;">
                  <img src="mr.jpg" width="250" height="250"
                       / title="This picture seems stable">
                       <br>
               </div>
               <div style="position:absolute;right: 5%; top: 3%;">
                  <img src="cv.jpg" width="250" height="250"
                       / title="this keeps moving to the left as I make my 
                       window smaller and smaller (resizing issue!)">
                       <br>
               </div>
               <h1>
                  <div>
                     <span style="color:#ff0000;">W</span>
                     <span style="color:#ff4000;">e</span>
                     <span style="color:#ff7f00;">l</span>
                     <span style="color:#ffff00;">c</span>
                     <span style="color:#80ff00;">o</span>
                     <span style="color:#00ff00;">m</span>
                     <span style="color:#00ffff;">e</span>
                     <span style="color:#0080ff;"> </span>
                     <span style="color:#0000ff;">t</span>
                     <span style="color:#4600ff;">o</span>

                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                     <span style="color:#8b00ff;"> </span>
                     <span style="color:#ff0000;">H</span>
                     <span style="color:#ff4000;">o</span>
                     <span style="color:#ff7f00;">w</span>
                     <span style="color:#ffff00;">T</span>
                     <span style="color:#80ff00;">o</span>
                     <span style="color:#00ff00;"> </span>
                     <span style="color:#00ffff;">.</span>
                     <span style="color:#0080ff;">.</span>
                     <span style="color:#0000ff;">.</span>
                  </div>
               </h1>
               </br>
               </br>
               </br>
               </br>
               </br>
               </br>
               </br>
               </br>
               </br>
               </br>
               </br>
               </br>
               </br>
               <h2>
                  <b>Try resizing the page on your window to see the issues</b>
               </h2>
               <p 
                  class="blocktext" 
                  align ="justify">
                  <font size="5">I gave up!!!! I tried my best to fix the problem 
                  but I have no clue. My problem is dealing with the resolution, 
                  the width, and the different computers. I manage to organize 
                  the page the way I wanted on my computer but every time I go 
                  check it on another computer I get frustrated. I don't know if 
                  someone could take a look at my CSS code and HTML code and give 
                  me some feedback; I would, really, appreciate it. My images move 
                  and overlap with the text and other images when I try resizing 
                  the page. The footer moves up if I opened the page on a larger 
                  screen. I don’t want the scroll bar to appear unless if it’s needed. 
                  Normally a good page everything will stay where it supposed to 
                  be and if you resize the page the scroll bar appears and allows 
                  you to see what you are interested in. I placed 4 images on the 
                  bottom of the page (web) and 3 on top.

                  I would appreciate it if someone could help with these issues. Thank you

                  </font></p>
               <a href="ex1.htm">
                  <div style="position:absolute;left: 25%; top: 70%;z-index:1;">
                     <img 
                        src="ex1.jpg" 
                        width="100" 
                        height="150" 
                        border="0" 
                        title="this moves up when I make the window smaller or using a different computer">
                     <br>
                  </div>
               </a>

               <a href="ex2.htm">
                  <div style="position:absolute;left: 40%; top: 70%;">
                     <img 
                        src="ex2.jpeg" 
                        width="100" 
                        height="150" 
                        border="0" 
                        title="this moves up when I make the window smaller or using a different computer">
                     <br>
                  </div>
               </a>

               <a href="ex3.htm" >
                  <div style="position:absolute; left: 55%; top: 70%;">
                     <img 
                        src="ex3.jpg" 
                        width="100" 
                        height="150" 
                        border="0" 
                        title="this moves up when I make the window smaller or using a different computer">
                     <br>
                  </div>
               </a>

               <a href="ex4.htm">
                  <div style="position:absolute;left: 70%; top: 70%;">
                     <img 
                        src="ex4.jpg" 
                        width="100" 
                        height="150" 
                        border="0" 
                        title="this moves up when I make the window smaller or using a different computer">
                     <br>
                  </div>
               </a>

            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="footerclear"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">

         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

         <font color="##FFFFFF" size="5">
         When I open this page on a bigger screen, this footer (the bar) moves up
         </font>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

here is my CSS code:

```
 html {
    background-image:url('tb.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
 }
 body {
    background-image:url('tb.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }
 div#mastercontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: auto;  <!--was: margin-bottom: -100px;-->
 }
 div#header {
    background-color: #383838;
    height: 30px;
 }
 div#footerclear {
 }
 div#footer {
    background-color: #383838;
    height: 60px;
 }
 h1
 {
    position:absolute;
    left:22%;
    top:13%;
 }
 h2 {
    text-align:center
 }
 P.blocktext {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60em
 }
 img
 {
    border-radius:500px/450px;
 }
 a:link {
    color:#6600FF
 }
 a {
    text-decoration:none;
 }
```

Comment: Would you mind putting together a quick fiddle so we can better see the issue?

Comment: You are using <br/> and &nbsp; to achieve layout goals.
This is not a good practice at all.
First step: remove them all and use css only to layout the page.

Comment: I tried editing your code in a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ewJyQ/ I removed the br and '&nbsp.' Its quite a mess. I think you need to start from scratch. Do you have an image of what you want this to look like? I could walk you through the steps. I just need to know what the specification is.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will send you a snapshot of the page I am trying to make, however what's the best way to send it to you. Thanks

Comment: The `<font>` tag, obsolete since 1998.

Comment: This is the best nerd joke I've seen in a while. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcrUp/). lolololol

Comment: Instead of getting someone to help; I am just getting bunch of...joking around